# satchmo no such table

Tags: django-models, django-admin, database-connection, satchmo, database-table

When ever i goto the admin and click i on any of the satchmo links i get

DatabaseError at /admin/product/category/
no such table: product_category
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    url.com/admin/product/category/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Exception Value:
no such table: product_category
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 234
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.5

category can be substituted with anything satchmo in the admim, such as, product, discounts, etc. all same error. this is a fresh satchmo package build using clonesatchmo.py.

Comment: Has been finished clonesatchmo without any reported error? Probably not. Do you see anything in satchmo.log immediately after clonesatchmo? Try it in a new directory or try `python manage.py syncdb` in the project directory. This should only create necessary tables without demo data.

Comment: thanks for your response. I didn't see anything in the logs. It was the demo that was screwing me up. i stop using the fixture and now it works.